# Suggestions of IDEs for Rich Internet Applications that will run in the browser (Windows, Mac, iOS)?

Tags: iphone, ipad

I'm looking for an IDE for developing Web apps.

My idea criteria are:
-A programming-like interface (from what I've seen a lot of FLASH IDE's are designed more for animation (although I hear that's better with Flex 4).

- Intelisense
- Step-by-step debugging - I have been told that this is a challenge for web apps.
- Easy to use and learn IDE
- Visual Development environment (arrange controls on the screen with drag'n drop)
- Completed app can run on any HTML5 compliant browser with Javascript(i.e., on the iPad, iPhone, Droid, Windows, Mac). So an IDE that supports the above and outputs Javascript +HTML +CSS would be fine.

My needs are pretty minimal:
-playing audio
-**Easily modify the UI**:  e.g, changing the pointer icon (so if they hover over a picture they can change by selecting another picture from a file, it might change to a folder icon).
-A **very responsive UI** (not having to submit a query to the server every-time they click).  E.g., we do things like having a message "Select a lesson to begin". When they select a lesson the message changes to "Click the Start button to begin".

I'm considering:

- [Real Software](http://realsoftware.com/) (formerly Real Basic).
- Unity  (impressive for games, but maybe overkill for my needs) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unity_%28game_engine%29
- [RunRev](http://www.runrev.com/) (formerly Runtime Revolution)

I'd love to hear pluses and minuses of the above platforms as well as any other suggestions. Please post your responses in the Answer for the particular solution (.e.,g all responses for RealSoftware as edits/comments in the Real Software answer).

Comment: It would be great if the IDE has an extensive support for SproutCore.

Comment: Can you define what you mean by "Complete Application", because HTML5 is still a document format + Javascript engine. So any IDE producing HTML5 would qualify. If you need to utilize the new HTML5 API such as DB, Storage, Location etc. I am not aware of any IDE supporting these natively yet. But Visual Studio Express 2010 is Drag'n'drop so is Adobe Dreamweaver

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question isn't very clear...you seme to be asking for an HTML 5 editor. Not sure if these will help, but here are some suggestions from wikipedia:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_Continuous_Integration_Software

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_HTML_editors

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_rich_Internet_application_frameworks

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_PIGUI_packages

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_rich_Internet_application_formats

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

I will have to heavily discourage the use of Unity for this task. 
It is not aimed for the type of development I am getting the impression you want to do.
It is also mainly a 3D tool, and working in 2D with it contains various quirks.
Lastly, they do not currently have a HTML backend, although I have heard they are planning on one using WebGL.
The unity web plugin only runs on windows and Mac OS. I.e deployment to android or iPhone is done through a binary build.

Comment: yup, Unity3D is a game engine, not an application engine.

Answer (score 0):

[Real Software](http://realsoftware.com/)

Pro's

- You can run the app as a web app (viewing it on iOS( iPad, iPhone), Mac, Windows, Linux)
- You can compile the same app to run natively (on Mac, Windows, Linux. Not sure about iOS)
- Intellisense
- Step by step debugging

Con's

- Special Server component. (It's not clear to me whether you could just put that library on your own server or whether you need a special hosting account).

Answer (score 0):

what about Eclipse? http://www.eclipse.org/

Answer (score 0):

All the IDEs in the market have the first three of your requirements:

- Intelisense
- Step-by-step debugging.
- Easy to use and learn IDE

For the wysiwyg part, Dreamweaver, VisualStudio and DashCode (part of Mac OS X's dev tools) are the only ones I know that have this functionality. However I'm not sure about Dreamweaver's ability to produce and work with HTML5, CSS3 or even JavaScript (I haven't used it in years) and DashCode (as of version 2.02) produces iPhone/iPod Touch only "apps". I can't tell for VisualStudio.

I saw [Radi](http://radiapp.com/) a few weeks ago but I didn't try it. It seems to be focused on the "WOW!" part of the HTML5 fad, though.

I didn't know about Real's effort in that area, it's probably worth having a look as Real Studio was quite good in the late 90's.

But whatever tool you use, an "HTML5 app" is nothing more than a bunch of HTML/CSS/JS files. This can be created with virtually any programming editor/IDE available and the "HTML5" moniker is often just an empty buzzword as most of what makes it cool (JS APIs, CSS3 animation, …) is available to any webpage, HTML5, HTML4, XHTML1…

Answer (score 0):

Google Web Toolkit (GWT) looks really cool. You write in Java (in Eclipse, etc.) and then it compiles it to Javascript, taking care of all cross browser support.
It's used within Google Adwors and Orkut. Free an open source.

Google has done all sorts of things to automatically speed up the code (compiling a version of your code for each browser, compressing images, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

RunRev's LiveCode is not good for web apps because it requires a browser plugin, which only runs in a 32-bit environment. It is possible, however, to use LiveCode to create standalone apps for iOS.